# Button inside combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, button, combobox

I am trying to add a button inside a combobox kind of 'Add New' and on clicking that a popup should appear where the user is prompted to add required data and that is stored inside the database and even combobox is refreshed after adding the data. I am creating the application in winforms.
Is it Possible? if yes, How?

Comment: Why did you want to add a button in combobox? If you want to add new items to it, you can set the value of the first item to "add new item" and bind it to the "SelectedIndexChanged" event. Like `private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ if(comboBox1.Text == "add new item") {  // add new items here }}`

Comment: Because it can make things faster for the users rather than going on a different page and then adding the item then coming back here this makes things faster for a company hence this feature is very useful for the company. And thanks for the help i'll try it